# How do I check an Impala query status in Hue?

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, hue, impala

From the Impala query editor in Hue you should be able to check query completion. But that is somewhat unreliable, since it sometimes gets stuck (i.e. 36%, even though the query might be progressing) and at that point you don't know if the query has completed.
From Hue Job Browser I can see Hive ans Spark jobs, but not impala.
Any place in Hue where I can find a reliable Impala query completion status progress?

Comment: And FYI there is a plan to add the Impala queries in the Job Browser at some point https://issues.cloudera.org/browse/HUE-1176

Answer (score 0):

You can go to impala statestore and get logs for impala queries. It is by default runs on 25010 port number.